# How to learn certain Maths to understand machine Learning papers?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematics, deep-learning

I have done the deeplearning.ai course on deep learning. But I cannot Understand equations like

```
minGmaxDV(D,G)=Ex∼pdata(x)[logD(x)]+Ez∼pz(z)[log(1−D(G(z)))]
```

What kind of Maths am I am supposed to learn? I know Calculus basic Multivariable Calculus and Linear Algebra. So should I learn Probability (Advance probability maybe)?

Comment: it would help if you could tell us which part you don't understand

Comment: I should you should instead focus on learning the notations rather than concepts.

Comment: I am confused about Expectation values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematical expectations are a concept from probability theory. Expressions like $E_x[...]$ denote [conditional expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation) and I think you will have trouble understanding Machine Learning concepts without understanding conditional expectations. (Understanding them *as a mathematical concept*, not on an intuitive level).

My recommendation is that you look for a beginner's course in probability theory to get a grasp of the following concepts:

- Random variables
- Probability distributions
- Stochastic independence
- Mathematical expectation
- Conditional expectation/conditional probability
- Law of total probability
- Bayes' theorem

There are probably courses designed specifically for people interested in Machine Learning.
Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

As Elias mentioned, the expectations are related to random variables and you would be good to go if you know about conditional probability, multivariate probability, joint and marginal distributions. I would suggest you take a course that has a syllabus on the lines of https://secure.oregonstate.edu/ap/cps/documents/view/134169.

Comment: +1 on multivariate probability, joint distributions and marginal distributions!

Answer (score 0):

you can study basic maths of a competitive examination maybe take 8-9 months of 10-11 hours studying each day say the JEE, but it is a prrofoundly the most optimal way you can study and grasp machine learning maths to the core of it - what seems time consuming at first provides fruits later - you can check out this channel for mathematics syllabus covered in depth for the JEE Advanced Examination, conducted in India - https://www.youtube.com/@MohitTyagi